# XML Code Not Working

Tags: android, xml

I am a beginner at coding Android Apps.
Here is my XML code under arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="difficulty">
        <item>"@string/easy_label"</item>
        <item>"@string/medium_label"</item>
        <item>"@string/hard_label"</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

"@string/easy_label" and the other labels are not highlighted a color.  I'm assuming my program won't run because there is a problem here.  Does anyone know how I can re-adjust this to make my Android program work?

On a side note: I have easy_label, medium_label, and hard_label all declared in strings.xml, so I don't think the reference to strings.xml is the problem.

Comment: If the highlighting (in Eclipse, I suppose) doesn't show the correct colors, you probably have a syntax error somewhere in your file. If you [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) your file or add it to your question we could have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you do it without double quotes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="difficulty">
        <item>@string/easy_label</item>
        <item>@string/medium_label</item>
        <item>@string/hard_label</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```